# Call that a fragment onInfoWindowClick the method

Tags: android

I have the code on the method onInfoWindowClick which works for me right now. I need to start a fragment in doing click on marker.

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

    String m = markerMap.get(marker.getId());

    if (m.equals("a1")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ActividadPrincipal.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (m.equals("b1")){
        Intent i = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ActividadPrincipal.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {

    final String m = markerMap.get(marker.getId());
    ......

    try {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                callFragment(m);
            }
        }, 100);


        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "Exception :: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void callFragment(String id) {
    YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("ID", id);
    fragment.setArguments(b);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dialog fragment. Here is small example:

Here is layout of your fragment_sample_dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dismiss"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dismiss" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is Dialogfragment java file:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample_dialog, container, false);
        getDialog().setTitle("Simple Dialog");
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here is instruction how you start your fragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment ();
dialogFragment.show(fm, "Sample Fragment");
```